# Dropping rows from a Dataframe based on Date

Tags: python

How can I drop rows from Dataframe `df` if the dates associated with `df['maturity_dt']` are less that today's date?

I am currently doing the following:

```
todays_date = datetime.date.today()
datenow = datetime.datetime.combine(todays_date, datetime.datetime.min.time()) #Converting to datetime
for (i,row) in df.iterrows():
    if datetime.datetime.strptime(row['maturity_dt'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') < datenow):
        df.drop(df.index[i])
```

However, its taking too long and I was hoping to do something like: `df = df[datetime.datetime.strptime(df['maturity_dt'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') < datenow`, but this results in the error `TypeError: must be str, not Series`

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried it but maybe the pandas native functions will iterate faster. Something like:

```
df['dt']=pandas.Datetimeindex(df['maturity_dt'])
newdf=df.loc[df['dt']<=todays_date].copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing the date in each row, you could format your comparison date in the same format as these dates are stored and then you could just do a string comparison.

Also, if there is a way to drop multiple rows in a single call, you could use your loop just to gather the indices of those rows to be dropped, then use that call to drop them in bunches.

Comment: Thank You. But I am just wondering how I would compare the two strings?